# UIAutomation: Check if element exists before tapping

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

We have a iPad app which includes a two-column news reader. The left view contains the list of news of which some link directly to a news and some push another view controller with another list of news. This will also cause a `UIButton` to be set as the `leftBarButtonItem` of the navigation bar. If we are on first level, a simple image that cannot be tapped will be the `leftBarButtonItem`.

My goal is now to have a test that taps every news on the first level. If a news leads to a second level list, it should tap the `UIButton` in the navigation bar.

How can I check, if the `leftBarButtonItem` is "tappable"? Since it can be either an image *or* a button, just calling `navigationBar().leftButton().tap()` will lead to an error if it's an image.

I'm also using the tuneup library if that's any help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Almost all elements in UIAutomation could be tapped. It does not matter if it is an Image, View or a Button. You will get an error in case an object you are trying to tap is invalid.
How to check:

```
if ( navigationBar().leftButton().checkIsValid() )
{
     navigationBar().leftButton().tap();
}
else
{
     //do what you need.
}
```

or you can check if an object you are trying to tap is a button, for example (not the best way but it works):

```
if ( navigationBar().leftButton().toString() == "[object UIAButton]" )
{
    navigationBar().leftButton().tap();
}
else
{
     //do what you need.
}
```

*checkIsValid()* is available for all UI elements. It will return *true* if an object exists.
*toString()* will return *[object UIAElementNil]* if element is invalid or will return *[object UIAButton]* or *[object UIAImage]*.

Also try to use Apple documentation: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAElementClassReference/UIAElement/UIAElement.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
if (navigationBar().leftButton().exists)
{
     navigationBar().leftButton().tap();
}
else
{
     //do what you need.
}
```